# Is it possible to restart a Vorpal application from the Vorpal prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal.js

Say we wanted to restart the Vorpal app from within the prompt.

Eg with a command:

> restart

I have tried different things including executing a shell script that kills the process and executes node app.js without luck

Any tips

Answer (score 1):

This would be the same problem as re-starting any Node add from within itself, really. The only difference is that you would have a Vorpal command trigger the action.

[Here](https://github.com/shimondoodkin/nodejs-autorestart) [are](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) [some](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) [libraries](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/comparison-tools-to-automate-restarting-node-js-server-after-code-changes-forever-nodemon-nodesupervisor-nodedev/) that try to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vorpal script that reloads the required files every time a command is executed.

```
const vorpal = require('vorpal')();

function genFn(name){
    return function(args, callback) {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./example.js')];
        const script = require('./example.js');
        script[name](args, callback);
    };
}

const commands = {
    'listAllRoles' : 'list all roles for development purposes',
};

for(var key in commands){
    vorpal
    .command(key, commands[key])
    .action(genFn(key));
}

vorpal
    .delimiter('example')
    .show();
```

And in `example.js`

```
module.exports.listAllRoles = function(args, callback) {
  this.log('bar');
  callback();
}
```